# Drop down list plus autopopulate data from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

How to use Name manager or VBA code to achieve the following?

I have sales data in Sheet 3 of 4 customers for 4 weeks.

In sheet 4 I need a dropdown list with these 4 Customer names and when I select a customer, their sales must auto populate the sales column.

What is the code for this please?

[image]

I tried name manager as of now and not able to auto populate the corresponding sales data for individual customers in Sheet 4.

Comment: Please edit your post to show the expected output on Sheet4.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim selectedCustomer As String
    Dim salesDataRange As Range
    Dim salesData As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Define the range containing customer names (Sheet1 B1:DQ1)
    Set salesDataRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:DQ1")
    
    ' Check if the change occurred in cell B1 (where the dropdown list is)
    If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then
        ' Get the selected customer name
        selectedCustomer = Target.Value
        
        ' Find the corresponding sales data for the selected customer
        For i = 1 To salesDataRange.Columns.Count
            If salesDataRange.Cells(1, i).Value = selectedCustomer Then
                ' Set the sales data range (Sheet1 B2:DQ13)
                Set salesData = salesDataRange.Offset(1, i - 1).Resize(13)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        
        ' Populate the sales data in Sheet2 B2:B13
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B13").Value = salesData.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

This code works and auto populates sales data for 120 customers. the format is like this [customers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqxZK.png)[dropdown customer list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkkcX.png)[data autopopulates for all customers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Alwwr.png)